# Three numbers, one of the number's digit sum is equal to two other digit difference

Tags: linear-algebra

So as the title says I need three numbers witch has this quality :
one of the numbers digit sum is equal to other two number differnce e.g.

I 68

II 52

III 97

third number digit sum is 16 and its equal to I and II difference which is 16.
So my question is this - is there a posibility that there is three nubmers that apply this quality more than once among the same numbers?
And if there is a such set, how is there some way to get it, and if there is not then why?

Comment: A trivial example is $1,2,3$ ($1 = 3-2$, $2 = 3-1$). Is that what you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 3 numbers a, b and c:
$$A = 10*a1 + a2\\
B = 10*b1 + b2\\
C = 10*c1 + c2$$

(in your example: a = 68 = 10*6 + 8)

The relation you are describing:
$$\begin{cases}
a1+a2 = C-B\\
b1+b2 = C-A
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
C = a1+a2+B\\
C = b1+b2+A
\end{cases}$$

$$a1+a2+B = b1+b2+A$$

$$a1+a2 + 10*b1+b2 = b1+b2 + 10*a1+a2$$

$$a1 + 10*b1 = b1 + 10*a1$$

$$a1=b1$$

So if a1 = b1 then you will always be able to find a number C that matches the relation.

For example a1=b1=5, a2=3, b2=9
$$A = 53\\
B = 59\\
=> C = 67
$$

Or in Vedran Šegos example a1=b1=0.